# asp.net strange exception every three minutes approximately

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to make a very simple aspx page that pulls some data from a mysql database.
The page builds without a problem. 
(the aspx contains just the default form and a div just to print some data)

Default.aspx.vb:

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data
Imports MySql
Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Partial Class _Default
     Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private cnstr As String =     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Item("thisdb").ConnectionString

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim cn As New MySqlConnection(cnstr)
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT user_firstname,user_lastname FROM tb_users;", cn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dim dt As DataTable
        dt = GetDataTableMySQL(cmd)
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            testdiv.InnerHtml = dt.Rows(0).Item("user_firstname")
            testdiv.InnerHtml += "<br/>" & dt.Rows(0).Item("user_lastname")
        End If
        dt.Dispose()
        cmd.Dispose()
        cn.Dispose()

    End Sub

    Private Function GetDataTableMySQL(ByVal cmd As MySqlCommand) As DataTable
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter()
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Try
           cmd.Connection.Open()
           da.SelectCommand = cmd
           da.Fill(dt)
           Return dt
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            Throw ex
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
        Finally
            cmd.Connection.Close()
            da.Dispose()
       End Try
    End Function

End Class
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="thisdb" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=mydatabase;Uid=mydbuser;Pwd=dbpasswd;CharSet=UTF8; "/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

When I browse to the page URL it runs perfectly. 
If I keep Refreshing the page, everything works without a problem.

Now comes the annoying problem...

**If I leave the page idle for approximately 3-4 minutes, and then hit Refresh I always get the following exception:**

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Exception: The given key was not present in
>   the dictionary.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Exception: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
>   _Default.GetDataTableMySQL(MySqlCommand cmd) +236    _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +112    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2207
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

If I hit Refresh once more, the page runs fine again... and so on.

After hours of searching on the web, the only thing that sounds 
related to my problem, has to do with mysql's Connector/Net:

The Connector/Net documentation says:

> Starting with MySQL Connector/Net 6.2, there is a background job that runs every three
>    minutes and removes connections from pool that have been idle (unused) for more than three minutes.
>    The pool cleanup frees resources on both client and server side. This is because
>    on the client side every connection uses a socket, and on the server side every
>    connection uses a socket and a thread.
>
> Prior to this change, connections were never removed from the pool, 
>    and the pool always contained the peak number of open connections.
>    For example, a web application that peaked at 1000 concurrent database 
>    connections would consume 1000 threads and 1000 open
>    sockets at the server, without ever freeing up those resources from the connection pool.
>
> Note, connections, no matter how old, will not
>    be closed if the number of connections in the pool is less than or equal to the value 
>    set by the Min Pool Size connection string parameter.

OK. Even if this is my problem, 
Which is the proper way to connect-->get data-->disconnect ?

Any ideas?  This is really driving me crazy!

**UPDATE**
After @Andrews suggestion, I changed the function "GetDataTableMySQL" as follows:

```
Private Function GetDataTableMySQL(ByVal cmd As MySqlCommand) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using da = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(dt)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

(It didn't solve the problem, but I think it is useful to show how the code looks now)

The exception's stack trace, changed to the following:

> [KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the
>   dictionary.]    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey
>   key) +9624829
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetCharacterSet(DBVersion version,
>   String CharSetName) +23
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.CharSetMap.GetEncoding(DBVersion version,
>   String CharSetName) +47
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Configure(MySqlConnection connection)
>   +510    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +418    System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
>   DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +123
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +166    System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable
>   dataTable) +115    _Default.GetDataTableMySQL(MySqlCommand cmd) +86
>   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +112    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2207

**UPDATE 2**  After reading the [Connector/Net Connection String Options Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net-connection-options.html)
I tested my connection-string with the option:

```
 Pooling=false;
```

and then I tested changing the pooling option to:

```
 Pooling=no;
```

By testing the Pooling options, the page never works!
I get the exception "The given key was not present in the dictionary" every time.

Answer (score 1):

It may not solve the problem, but for DataAdapter.Fill you don't need to open and close the connection yourself.

Also, I'm suspicious of using Return in a Try block - you could do something more like

```
Private Function GetDataTableMySQL(ByVal cmd As MySqlCommand) As DataTable
    Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
    Using da = New MySqlDataAdapter()
        da.fill(dt)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

and check if the return value IsNot Nothing to make sure it worked.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Andrew!  I am trying your suggestion now!  Very strange though...I never had this problem with **MS-SQL** and this function

Comment: OK I changed the function and tested... Unfortunately, I get the same exception "The given key was not present in the dictionary", after the page is idle for 3-4 minutes  :(

Comment: I think the database may not be the issue, see, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552280/asp-net-mvc-the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary